# Bower install - failed with ETIMEDOUT

Tags: bower, bower-install

When I run `bower install`, I get the following error:

> Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery failed with
>   ETIMEDOUT,
>       retrying in 1.8s

But when I run the same URL in the address bar of Chrome, I get the json. I don't know why it fails when I do `bower install` using Windows 7 command shell. I suspect it has got something to do with my workplace's proxy settings.

Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried something like `http_proxy='proxyserver' https_proxy='proxyserver' bower install`? (where proxyserver is your proxy)

Comment: @MangledDeutz I tried `set HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy:8080` and `set HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy:8080` and it worked! Post your comment as answer below so that I can accept it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried something like `http_proxy='proxyserver' https_proxy='proxyserver' bower install?` (where proxyserver is your proxy)

Comment: are you setting these values in npm via "npm config set" command?

Comment: no, these are environment variables. Try `set HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy:8080` on your shell (I assume you are on windows?)

Comment: Thank you.  That did not help me, unfortunately. I had to change the git to use the https instead of git protocol to work behind the proxy.

Answer (score 18):

Try edit .bowerrc

```
"proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"strict-ssl": false
```

Comment: where is this file on mac

Answer (score 9):

Getting error related to proxy when no proxy is configured: May be `npm` is picking up proxy.

Delete the proxy attribute from `npm` config and try. Use:

```
npm config delete proxy
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: `npm config delete proxy` worked for me. I was getting the same error. I'm not using a proxy. I tried `npm clean cache` and `bower clean cache` but neither worked for me. Thank you my friend :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the new registry for bower in .bowerrc:

```
{
  "registry": "https://registry.bower.io"
}
```

The old url https://bower.herokuapp.com/ is no more available.

Comment: Confirming that this works for me too.  If there is already a .bowercc and it has "directory": "wwwroot/lib" in it, just put a comma on that line, and on the next line insert registry.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Win7), this problem was fixed by providing bower with the proxy settings.

As @Robert Moon mentioned in his answer, you can place this settings in the .bowerrc file.

For proxies that require authentication you will need to provide it as follows:

```
http://domain\username:password@proxyserverurl:port
```

The **back slash** is particularly tricky since it needs to be escaped in the .bowerrc file

**Example .bowerrc:**

```
{
  "directory": "bower_components",
  "proxy": "http://domain%5Cusername:password@proxyserverurl:port",
  "https-proxy": "http://domain%5Cusername:password@proxyserverurl:port",
  "no-proxy":"localserver.domain.com"
}
```

The official documentation from Bower that mentions proxy settings:
https://bower.io/docs/config/#bowerrc-specification

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same error. The following steps fixed the error for me:

1. Remove any existing proxy: `npm config delete proxy`

Then set proxy using: `npm config set proxy http://<host>:<port>`

2. You may also need to change the proxy settings for git:

   `git config --global http.proxy http://<host>:<port>`
3. Now edit the .bowerrc file as described by [Robert Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915961/bower-install-failed-with-etimedout/33644595#33644595)

`"proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
 "https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
 "strict-ssl": false`

Comment: it is  necessary to reset the PC? Thanks

Comment: I didn't need to reset the PC. Just try if it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Prod server build bower well, but the develop server does not build, it is stop with ETIMEDOUT.
The error went through when I added:

> "timeout": 120000

into .bowerrc.

Info from page https://bower.io/docs/config/ helped me.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Instead, please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).