# Bower behind a proxy, still does not work after settinmg a proxy

Tags: git, proxy, cygwin, yeoman, bower

i want to use yeoman behind a proxy but so far i fail. I set up the proxy using the enviorment variables. I get the following ENOTFOUND.

```
C:\test>bower search jquery
bower ENOTFOUND     Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/jquery   failed: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

I tried i can reach https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/jquery via the browser using my proxy settings. I set before as a trial:

```
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
```

However seems when i set

```
git config --global --unset url."https://".insteadOf
```

it does not have any effect if bower uses git or https.

I'm running on win7 64bit.

C:\test>bower -version
1.3.1

Please help somebody.

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `http_proxy='proxyserver' https_proxy='proxyserver' bower install`? (where proxyserver is your proxy) - or setting the env vars then calling bower?

See [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915961/bower-install-failed-with-etimedout).

Comment: Hi Mangled, <p> thanks seems it was a proxy issue but there were several issues. One was i sent my https proxy to https.proxy.... instead of http.proxy.

Comment: This was one life Saver !!