# bower register fails with ETIMEDOUT

Tags: bower, bower-register

after hours of search, I try my luck here now: I have a repository, which I would like to register as a bower component. Running `bower register` results directly in an ETIMEDOUT error - from my local machiene as well as from my server.

This is the stack:

```
bower dwbn-theme#*             resolve git://gitlab.dwbn.org/dw-connect/dwbn-theme.git#*
bower dwbn-theme#*            checkout v1.1.6
bower dwbn-theme#*            resolved git://gitlab.dwbn.org/dw-connect/dwbn-theme.git#1.1.6? Registering a package will make it installable via the registry (https://bower.herokuapp.com), continue? Yes
bower dwbn-theme              register git://gitlab.dwbn.org/dw-connect/dwbn-theme.git
bower                        ETIMEDOUT Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages?access_token=658cbd3fe9b6251d2a910528e9959c4027c51134 failed: ETIMEDOUT
```

I checked th internet and the closest answer I could find was connected to a proxy server (which I dont have): [Bower install - failed with ETIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915961/bower-install-failed-with-etimedout)

Using `npm config delete proxy` as suggested also did not help.

Is there anything else, whch could solve this issue?

Thx a lot
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an short update, how we solved this in the end:

Bower allows to include also a repository directly without registering it and we simply went this way in the bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dwbn-theme": "ssh://git@gitlab.dwbn.org/dw-connect/dwbn-theme.git#~1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3",
    "jquery": "~2.1",
    "lama-on-tour-flickr-stream": "ssh://git@gitlab.dwbn.org/dw-connect/lama-on-tour-flickr-stream.git#~1.0"
  }
```

Since the dwbn-theme is verry specific to our charity, there is also no additional benefit to make it public worldwide.

Hope this helps

Andreas