# Bower install fails with ETIMEDOUT in EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bower, bower-install

I ran `bower install`from my EC2 Ubuntu instance and got `Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/foundation-sites failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.4s`.

`npm install` works and Bower is installed globally

I added the instance to a security group that allows all inbound and outbound for the purpose of this issue, still not working.

I know about Elastic Beanstalk and the likes but interested in how to make this work from my EC2 instance.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915961/bower-install-failed-with-etimedout

Comment: @Conti I saw that before asking this. I doubt if this problem has anything to do with proxy. AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance remember

Comment: I have launched an Ubunut AMI in EC2 and followed this instructions to get Npm and Bower running, and I had no problem at all: https://syntaxsugar.github.io/posts/2014/05/how-to-install-bower-on-ubuntu-1404-lts/  . FYI, the machine is inside a VPC, with default security group

Comment: This is embarrassing. Fixed it. Appeared there was proxy set up in `.bowerrc`. Must have slipped in from my work machine which is behind a proxy. I thought I removed it before commit. Thanks @Conti, your second link led me to spot the oversight. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Edit .bowerrc to below and then try the install.

```
"proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"strict-ssl": false
```