# During Ember setup, I am getting a "ETIMEDOUT error"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am running the following commands to setup my Ember project;

```
npm install
bower --force install
ember generate my-addon
```

While setting up, I am getting some errors as below;

```
installing my-addon
install bower packages ember, jquery-ui, jqwidgets, moment, blueimp-file-upload, d3, nvd3, jquery-cookie
cached
cached
cached
cached
cached
cached
cached
cached
cached
new version for
cached
progress received 2.1MB of 3.8MB downloaded, 55%
progress received 2.3MB of 3.8MB downloaded, 62%
progress received 2.6MB of 3.8MB downloaded, 69%
progress received 2.9MB of 3.8MB downloaded, 77%
progress received 3.2MB of 3.8MB downloaded, 85%
progress received 3.5MB of 3.8MB downloaded, 93%
{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.196.100:443]
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '216.58.196.100',
port: 443 }
resolved
Installed browser packages via Bower.
Installed my-addon - jQWidgets
Installed my-addon images
Installed my-addon assets to addon dummy app
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Bower is erroring out due to an issue with a proxy server.  Here's a related question that might move you in the right direction: [Bower install - failed with ETIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915961/bower-install-failed-with-etimedout)